# Can the points at which a series of real valued functions converge form a meagre subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is this possible except for the case where such set of points is just a singleton?

Comment: If a single point counts as an interval, and a unions of disjoint intervals also counts, what sets do not count?

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry, I meant to say meagre and dense. Will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be any meagre subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Define $f_i(x)$ to be $0$ on $M$ and to be $(-1)^i$ otherwise. Then the $f_i(x)$ only converge on the points of $M$.

Comment: I meant real valued functions whose domain is real line.

Comment: These functions are real valued with domain the real line.  Is there another property you need them to have?

Comment: $i$ seemed iota (still it would have been real).

Comment: Sorry if that confused - I should have used n.